# xset in bash script not working

Tags: bash, shell, xorg

A little background: I want to use the wrapper script for i3lock I use on my laptop on my desktop as well.
So, as the title says, i can use

```
xset dpms 2
```

in a shell, and it does what it is supposed to do, but when i use it in a script, e.g.

```
#!/bin/sh

revert() {
    xset dpms 0 
}

trap revert INT 
xset dpms 2
i3lock "$@"
revert
```

it doesn't do trick.

with `bash -x` I get the output

```
+ trap revert INT
+ xset dpms 2
+ i3lock
+ revert
+ xset dpms 0
```

I am not sure what the problem is. It's the same when i put `#!/bin/bash` instead of `#!/bin/sh` in the first line.

Comment: If you added `echo $?` after `xset dpms 2` line, what would it say? From what you say, there does not seem to be any failure, but just to make sure. Another ideas: when you say doesn't work I presume you mean your monitor does not enter standby as you would expect. Could it be though, that i3lock replaces what you've specified with its own setting? What would `xset q` say if you placed it right before and just past `i3lock`?

Comment: @OndrejK. `echo $?` got me an exit code of 0 and `xset q` before and after had the lines `DPMS (Energy Star):  
  Standby: 2 [...]`

Comment: That would suggest that xset did not only ran OK, but also did what it was supposed to. At this point, I would suspect `i3lock` to be affecting your DPMS behavior, but DPMS code was dropped from it back in 2011 and I do not suppose you'd be running a version that old? One more guess if `DISPLAY` was messed up in the scripts env, it could be talking to a server other than expected? May be one step back to clarify, by not work you mean the monitor does not go enter lower energy like you would expect. But it would do so when just setting DPMS and not engaging i3lock?

Comment: @OndrejK. I've already checked DISPLAY, seems to be the same. When I get back home I will try not calling i3lock. The i3lock version at home is up to date, the version on my laptop *might* not be up to date. I will be back when I investigated further.

Answer (score 1):

I just stumbled upon the same issue, and finally fixed it using the `-n` switch (nofork) of i3lock.

What is hapening is that the dpms gets set to 3, then i3lock is launched and forked, and immediatly after that, the `revert` function gets called while i3lock is still running, negating the first call to xset.

Using `i3lock -n` prevents this behaviour, making sure the script continues past the i3lock line only when i3lock has exited.

Just replace `i3lock "$@"` with `i3lock -n "$@"` and it should work as intended.